# Inject String into Page Source in Real Time...Possible?

Tags: javascript, html, divx

I wonder if we can add a string into pagesource in real time..
to give an example, and the thing I want to do is to control timestamps of Divx Videos..

Let me give u an example..

> http://www.movshare.net/embed/v5alr3gpmu2nt/?width=720&height=306

when we push play button in this video link it will generate following parameters

```
<object width="640" height="318"
id="objectmvshre"
codebase="http://go.divx.com/plugin/DivXBrowserPlugin.cab"
classid="clsid:67DABFBF-D0AB-41fa-9C46-CC0F21721616">
<param value="none"
name="custommode"/> <param
value="false" name="autoPlay"/> <param
value="false" name="bannerEnabled"/>
<param value="auto"
name="bufferingMode"/>

<param
value="http://stream.movshare.net/v5alr3gpmu2nt.avi?8870706d6e17b351bc49a277521bce4f73877a79c281bab9c057f9fe55db14d22958952baaca29&amp;ec_rate=45"
name="src"/>
<embed width="640" height="318"
pluginspage="http://go.divx.com/plugin/download/" custommode="none" autoplay="false"
bufferingmode="auto"
bannerenabled="false" id="embedmvshre"
src="http://stream.movshare.net/v5alr3gpmu2nt.avi?8870706d6e17b351bc49a277521bce4f73877a79c281bab9c057f9fe55db14d22958952baaca29&amp;ec_rate=45"
type="video/divx"/>

</object>
```

To be able to control timestamp of a Divx Player, I should be able to add

```
<param>name="timecallback" value="XXX"/>
```

Is there a way to inject this parameter into page source while I'm browsing a video on a page ?

If it is possible, and if it requires deep coding, please let me know..
I would want to open a project about this on Elance or Scriptlance sites..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just have a `<span>` tag on the page and then populate the contents of that span.innerHTML to be the parameter tag you want to add.

```
<input type="button" value="Play" onclick="javascript:loadParams();" />

<span id="myParams"></span>

<script language="javascript">
   function loadParams()
   {
      document.getElementById('myParams').innerHTML = "<param>";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried that but no luck..my test page is http://online-dizi-film-izle.com/www/

I had a programmer to play subtitle file above the video..he created a js for this..so when you click the buttons below the video, as we control timestamp of divx player by adding timecallback paramater, subtitles also play along with video..

you can see my index.php content from http://pastebin.com/d461762a8